# Azure active directory with spring boot Oaut2UserService Problem

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory

Description:

Field oidcUserService in com.azure.spring.aad.webapp.AADWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.OAuth2UserService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.OAuth2UserService' in your configuration.

SecurityConfig.java

```
   @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    @Profile("azure")
    public class SecurityConfig extends AADWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Value( "${app.protect.authenticated}")
        private String[] protectedRoutes;

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();

}

}
```

If I compare my SecurtiyConfig.java with couple of other tutorials its very similar. Or at least they have no OAuth2UserService Bean in the SecurityConfig. Thats what I don't understand.
Anybody able to help?
https://code-premium.exaas.bosch.com/ps.go/msal-search-users/-/tree/main/1-Authentication/sign-in

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below work arounds

1. Please Check dependencies:
   azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter  and spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client.
2. In security configuration try this

```js
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
              .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                .oidcUserService(oidcUserService);
```

3. Also check if it is indentation issue in your application.yml file or application.properties . security property must be beneath the spring property and so on

```js
 azure:
      activedirectory:
        tenant-id: <tenant-id>
    //other
```

```js
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
       //other
```

Please refer this [Spring Boot Starter for Azure Active Directory developer's guide | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/spring-boot-starter-for-azure-active-directory-developer-guide)

Comment: Unfortunately is you idea not working. Whenn I add the .oidUserService(oidcUserService) I still need this UserService and I don't know where it should come from.

Comment: I also doublechecked the indentation in the application.yml. Semms correct from my point of view. What my application.yml doesn't contain is that second spring: secturity: oauth2: client:. Do I really need that? I was not able to find it in the documentation which you posted.

Comment: I'm getting `Could not find com.microsoft.azure:azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter`, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by adding the following to my application.properties file

```
azure.activedirectory.tenant-id=YOUR_TENANT_ID
azure.activedirectory.client-id=YOUR_APPLICATION_ID
azure.activedirectory.client-secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
azure.activedirectory.post-logout-redirect-uri=REDIRECT_URI
azure.activedirectory.autorization-clients.graph.scopes=APP_SCOPES
```